# Sending post data from angularjs to django as JSON and not as raw content

Tags: python, django, angularjs, http-post

I have a request like this:

```
$http({ 
    method: 'POST', 
    url: '/url/', 
    data: 'test=data'
})
```

In my django views:

```
class SomeClass(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return HttpResponse("Hello")
    def post(self, request):
        print request.post
        print request.body
        return HttpResponse("Done")
```

So when I do `request.POST`  I get an empty query dict :`<QueryDict: {}>`

But my `request.body` has: `test=data`

So I believe django receives the data as url-encoded parameters and not as a dictionary.

How do I send or receive this data as JSON/Dict ?

Comment: Is the code correct? I think you should use request.POST instead of request.post.

Comment: Instead of `data`, try `params` and give an object instead of string. Ref: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http#parameters

Answer (score 44, accepted):

When calling ajax, you recieve encoded json string in request body, so you need to decode it using python's json module to get python dict:

```
json.loads(request.body)
```

Comment: I like this solution because I can use AngularJS as it was designed instead of hacking it to work as I'm used to working with jQuery.

Comment: Beautiful idiomatic method.

Comment: If you are using angular 4 and DRF use `request.data`.

Answer (score 14):

In my case works something like

```
$http({
    url: '/url/',
    method: "POST",
    data: $.param(params),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
    }
})
```

Or more nice variant:

```
app.config ($httpProvider) ->
    ...
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

and then

```
$scope.save_result = $http.post('/url/', $.param(params))
```

http://www.daveoncode.com/2013/10/17/how-to-make-angularjs-and-django-play-nice-together/

Answer (score 2):

I am using zope2 where I used [simplejson](https://github.com/simplejson/simplejson) to decode the request json into python dictionary as:

```
request_dict = simplejson.loads(request.get('BODY','')
```

It's working correctly for me. In this way I am able to use angularjs default json request rather than converting it into form post.

Comment: saved the day for me

Answer (score 2):

I improved mariodev's solution a bit by creating a decorator:

```
# Must decode body of angular's JSON post requests
def json_body_decoder(my_func):
    def inner_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
        body = request.body.decode("utf-8")
        request.POST = json.loads(body)
        return my_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return inner_func

 @json_body_decoder
 def request_handler(request):
     # request.POST is a dictionary containing the decoded body of the request
```

Now I just add the `@json_body_decoder` decorator whenever I create a request handler that deals with post data in `application/json`.

Answer (score 1):

For angular 4 and Django Rest Framework use `request.data` to get json object.

like:

`posted_data = request.data`

Answer (score 0):

The `$http` service expects a JS object, not a string. Try this:

```
$http({ 
    method: 'POST', 
    url: '/url/', 
    data: {test: 'data'}
})
```